# .NET Core SDK - Multiple folders to resolve SDK

Tags: c#, .net-core, sdk

My current situation is that for testing reasons I need multiple versions of .NET Core SDK. The thing that those should not exists in the default path.

So currently when I run `dotnet --list-sdks` I have:

```
3.1.405 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

What I would like is to have:

```
2.1.300 [C:\Legacy\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.405 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

The questions boils down to if you can say somehow to search more than one directory for SDKs

Comment: You may add `C:\Legacy\dotnet\sdk` to `PATH` variable

Comment: Thanks @PavelAnikhouski I had already done that but it seems it to be added in a special way for it to work(see my answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out what is happening. Although I did added the path to the PATH variable it did not work.

You **must** have the path above/first than default one. So if you have:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet;
C:\Legacy\dotnet;
```

It will not work

But if you change it before:

```
C:\Legacy\dotnet;
C:\Program Files\dotnet;
```

It will work.